# Razor UMBRACO show PDF files

Tags: pdf, razor, umbraco

I've got the following in umbraco 6.

I have a folder structure in the Media section:

Media
-files
--PDF

the ID of the PDF folder is "2465".

How do I get Umbraco to show all the PDF files which are located in the PDF folder? I have already setup the template, documenttypes and macro.

the Macro Alias is called ViewPDF and points to ViewPDF.cshtml file. All I need is the CSHTML code. What I have tried so far isn't working.

Below is one of my snippets that I've tried:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
```

@using umbraco.MacroEngines;

@{
    int mediaFolderId = 2465;

```
DynamicMedia folder = new DynamicMedia(mediaFolderId);

    <div class="ViewPDF">
        @foreach (dynamic media in folder.Children.Items)
    {
            if (media.ContentType.Alias  == "ViewPDF")
            {

                  <a href="@media.umbracoFile"><img src="css/pdf.png" alt="ViewPDF" /></a>

            }
    }
    </div>
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try using folder.Children instead folder.Children.Items

Comment: deleting .items didn't help.

Is the code correct at all, am I using the right properties etc.? is more info needed to give a better answer?

Comment: Just to make sure, which media type are you using for your pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this:

```
var myContent = Umbraco.TypedContent(id); -> For content nodes.
```

This will return `IPublishedContent`. So you can then query in this way:

```
var something = myContent.GetProperty("myAlias")
```

Check it [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/querying).

In U6 you can also use the [Content Service](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService)

EDIT- Snipet:

```
@{
    var rootNode = Umbraco.TypedMedia(1078);
    foreach (var item in rootNode.Children)
    {
         <p>@item.DocumentTypeAlias - @item.Id - @item.GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile")</p>
    }
}
```

So, I'm hardcoding the node on the media folder that I am querying, in you case could be 2465. Altought I wouldn't hardcode this... query it by it's type, if it's a custom one, get that one.

And this is the output of the snipet:

File - 1079 - /media/1001/1452119_10152065755207915_1678786930_n.jpg

File - 1080 - /media/1002/gumkfjn.png

Image - 1081 - /media/1003/tumblr_madtynbo2m1r54uxao1_400.jpg

These are the 3 children that I had above the hardcoded node, I'm printing their type alias, the id, and the umbraco file path property. You can sort the children, or query them by a certain document type.

For example:

```
rootNode.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("File"))
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate))
```

This will only return me the nodes that are "File" ordered by "CreateDate".

Comment: hello thanks for your answer. I'm havin issues getting this to work, could you please help me by writing the entier code snippet? That way I can see what I did wrong in my attempts.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to answer me! :) I'm trying to use the: @inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage in the begenning, but it returns with and error: d:\web\localuser\MYWEBPAGE\public_html\MacroScripts\635221538203258173_ViewPDFv2.cshtml(8): error CS1061: 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent' does not contain a definition for 'GetPropertyValue' and no extension method 'GetPropertyValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Any suggestions?